# Can I arrive in the USA before my estimated date?

Tags: visas, usa

When I filled the B1/B2 visa related questions (the D-160 form), I mentioned I do not know when I will go to the US, but I estimated to arrive in April 2020.

The interview went well and I received the visa, and I think it is already active, starting with this year.

Will there be any problem if I will arrive, let's say, in February 2020?

Should I have the return flight tickets when entering the US? My travel schedule is quite flexible and I usually buy the tickets just a few weeks before I travel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no problem.  US visas are valid from the date of issue.

Lying to a consular officer can result in permanent inadmissibility, but since you said that you were not certain about your travel plans, you haven't lied.

Return or onward tickets are not required for visitors with a B visa (they are required for most visitors using the visa waiver program).  However, the officer at the border may investigate whether you have the means to leave the US at the end of your visit.  If you don't have a ticket when you arrive, you may be  asked to show that you have the means to pay for one, and you are probably more likely to have to show ties to your place of residence.  If the duration of your visit is indeterminate when you arrive, you will probably be asked to show how you can support yourself for up to six months without working.